# Error for azure function created on visual studio with NotificationHub Integration

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-notificationhub

I am getting an error for an azure function when is deployed on azure where the func cannot find the notification hub connection string settings.

```
Error indexing method 'NotifyMobiles.Run'Unable to resolve app setting for property 'NotificationHubAttribute.ConnectionStringSetting'. Make sure the app setting exists and has a valid value.
```

The function signature looks like below and I am getting weird error that I believe is result of being using beta library(Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs) and is that the deployed function is looking for connections strings that have prefixed AzureWebJobs even is the connections string is named SERVICEBUS in the app setting. Thus I added the prefix to avoid the error and is finding now the Service bus element but no the Notification Hub

```
        [FunctionName("NotifyMobiles")]
        public static async Task Run(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("MobileNotifications", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "SERVICEBUS")] QueueItem queueItem, 
            TraceWriter log,
            [NotificationHub(HubName = "push-notification-hub", ConnectionStringSetting = "NOTIFICATIONHUB", TagExpression = "{Tag}")] IAsyncCollector<Notification> notification)
        {}
```

[image]

Comment: So don't add the prefix for notification hub setting? :)

Comment: If I dont add the prefix I get an error I get this error Error indexing method 'TriggerSendNotification.Run'Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK ServiceBus connection string 'AzureWebJobsSERVICEBUS' is missing or empty. where the applications is looking for a connection string with that prefix. It happens for both Service bus and Notification Hub. When I add the prefix I start having the error listed here

Comment: Mikhail do you have insider knowledge? I removed just for the   NOTIFICATIONHUB the prefix and deleted the connection string key and is working

Comment: That's what I meant, sorry if I was too vague

Comment: It is OK if you want you can add it as a reply so I will mark the question as solved and other people can see quickly the solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the "AzureWebJobs" prefix from "NOTIFICATIONHUB" setting name. It should match `ConnectionStringSetting` value in your code.

You may delete the connection string key.